# How to use charts in maximo anywhere 7.5.2 for mobile app

Tags: charts, maximo-anywhere

I am working on the maximo anywhere 7.5.2 for mobile app. 
I supposed to be use chart in mobile app to display the technician's work order as a report. I don't know how to use the chart in maximo anywhere.Please let me know whether it is possible to use chart in anywhere mobile or not. If yes,kindly help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There's no chart widget developed for use declaratively in MaximoAnywhere's app.xml. However you should be able to with JavaScript programmatically add and bind your own JavaScript widgets.